# ggplot adding multiple geom_lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame :

```
df <- data.frame(z = c(2,1,2,3,2,3,2,1,1,1,3,4,1,1,2,3,4,3),
                 x = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c"),
                 cat = c("A","A", "B","B","C", "C", "A","A", "B","B","C","C","A","A", "B","B","C","C"))
```

Here I am plotting on the x-axis categorical values from x (3 categories: a,b,c).
On the y axis a mean value for values in "z" counted for:

```
all x="a" and cat="A"
all x="b" and cat="B"
all x="c" and cat="C"
```

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(cat,x) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(z)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=avg, group=cat, color=cat)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

I would like to add one more line to the plot which is an avg across all 3 "cat" and also include that in a legend.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rbind`:

```
rbind(
  df %>% group_by(cat,x) %>% 
         summarise(avg = mean(z)),
  df %>% group_by(cat='Mean',x) %>% 
    summarise(avg = mean(z))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=avg, group=cat, color=cat)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `tidyverse`, we could use `group_map` with `add_row` to create an additional row

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
    group_by(cat, x) %>%
    summarise(avg = mean(z), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    group_by(x) %>%
    group_map(~ .x %>% 
        add_row(cat = 'mean', x = first(.x$x),
              avg = mean(.x$avg) ), .keep = TRUE) %>%
    bind_rows %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=x, y=avg, group=cat, color=cat)) + 
     geom_point() +
     geom_line()
```

-output

[image]

---

Or do this in a concise way by making use of `summarise` property after the first `summarise` concatenate the addtional rows in 'cat' and 'avg' columns, and then use the `ggplot` code from OP's post

```
df %>% 
    group_by(x, cat) %>%
    summarise(avg = mean(z), .groups= 'drop_last') %>% 
    summarise(cat = c(cat, 'mean'), 
              avg = c(avg, mean(avg)), .groups = 'drop') %>%   
    ggplot(aes(x=x, y=avg, group=cat, color=cat)) + 
     geom_point() +
     geom_line()
```

---

Or we can reshape to 'wide' to get the `mean` and reshape back to 'long'

```
library(tidyr)
 df %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = cat, values_from = z, values_fn = mean) %>%
     mutate(mean = rowMeans(select(cur_data(), where(is.numeric)))) %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -x, names_to = 'cat', values_to = 'z')  %>%
     ggplot(aes(x=x, y=avg, group=cat, color=cat)) + 
       geom_point() +
       geom_line()
```

---

Or a `base R` option

```
out <- xtabs(z ~ x + cat, df)/xtabs(z ~ x + cat, transform(df, z = 1))
out1 <- cbind(out, mean = rowMeans(out))
matplot(out1, type = 'l',  col=c("blue","green","red", "black"), lty = 1:4)
legend('left', legend = colnames(out1), col=c("blue","green","red", "black"), lty = 1:4)
```

-output

[image]